# Can I host the front-end of a web application on a product like Parse, and host the applications backend/API on a platform like heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, web-applications, web-hosting

I am building a web application (crowdfunding site). I have started building the REST backend using ruby on rails.

I plan on deploying the backend to heroku.

I then plan on developing the front-end using some js framework like Backbone or Angular, html, and css.

My question is, can I host the front-end using a product like Parse? Such that the front-end has access to the exposed api endpoints hosted on heroku.

If not, what are my front-end hosting alternatives?

Will I need to reconsider using heroku for the API/backend?

This is my first time building a web application, so I would appreciate details and other resources. Thanks!